# How to open up a zoom meeting url in device's browser in xamarin.forms?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, safari, xamarin.ios, zoom-sdk

I want to open up zoom meeting url from my app in device's browser, i.e. Safari in iOS and Google chrome in Android.

Here is the url of zoom meeting: [Meeting ID](https://us04web.zoom.us/j/9218226818?pwd=ZmdXcjJ3Z2RqcUE4UzBmVnhwWUNsdz09)

I have successfully opened up this url in browser using Xamarin.Essential:

```cs
public async void Button_Clicked(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    var zoomMeetUrl = "https://us04web.zoom.us/j/7850637100?
                       pwd=bnJwWC8xOHZod2VyMzZlMFAzUkJ5QT09";
    await Browser.OpenAsync(zoomMeetUrl, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
}
```

---

But in iOS when I click on Launch meeting button in browser it gives this error message:

> Safari cannot Open the Page because the Address Is Invalid

Does anyone know, how to fix this problem?

[image]

```css
Note: Zoom app is installed in my device, still it gives same message.
```

Comment: is the Zoom app installed on the device?

Comment: Yes, its installed.